# how to implement load balancer for Jboss

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, jboss, java-6

We have a legacy java application which is developed in 2010 deployed in Jobss 5. we cant migrate to latest one because of some business and other constrain.

we have deployed our applicationin AWS, there are 9 servers and one load balancer.

We want to add and remove servers based on the health endpoint.
this is an ejb application and exposing soap service, we cant have GET call for a health endpoint.

So I am thinking to build a custom load balancer which will be a wrapper on top of these 9 servers which is a tedious task as I have to write a wrapper for each soap service around (1000 services)

is there a  better way to handle this, any pointer will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Did you think about using something like nginx?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to call the actual services (with POST) to see if they are alive, or what do you mean with you can't have a GET endpoint? Is there a health SOAP endpoint, or are there just "real" endpoints that do things when you call them? Many SOAP services return WSDL if called with GET, you might use that as a health probe of sorts.

Comment: will check nginx @dan1st

Comment: @ewramner   we need to call POST to check health

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add an additional servlet to the JBoss deployment that provides a GET route.
- Call the existing SOAP service (or whatever is needed to verify health) internally.
- Use AWS Application Load Balancer and configure the target group health check (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html).

You may want to combine it with a Facade using Amazon API Gateway. That would allow you to incrementally modernize in the future (e.g. you could run the Java code providing the SOAP services in a serverless way as a AWS Lambda function).